# Get access to document lang or url when lazy loading routes in an SSR-friendly way

Tags: angular

I know what I'm asking is probably impossible, but I need a way to obtain the `lang` attribute set on the `html` element when lazy loaded routes are loaded so I can iterate over them and replace their `path` property, as I do for the root routes easily using the `APP_INITIALIZER` provider along with `this.router.reset(myTranslatedRoutes)`.

However, to do this in an SSR-friendly way for lazy loaded routes is proving difficult since I can't seem to inject the `DOCUMENT` token, and using `document` directly breaks when the code runs on the server.

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'testing',
    loadChildren: () => {

        return import('./my-lazy-loaded-routes').then(m => {
     
          const _document = inject(DOCUMENT); // doesn't work in browser or on server
          const lang = document.documentElement.lang; // doesn't work on server

          return translateRoutes(m.MyLazyLoadedRoutes, lang); 
        });
    }
  }
];
```

*I've excluded the code for the translation part as it's not relevant to the problem.*

So my question is, is there any way of obtaining the `lang` attribute value OR getting the language through other means such as accessing the current url like `http://localhost:4000/en/myroute` and extracting the `en` part?

**EDIT:**
I got intrigued by the bootstrapping process in `main.ts`:

```
export const ApplicationRefPromise = bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig);
```

which gives access to an `ApplicationRef` instance which has an injector which would work in the context I need it to. But, I cannot figure out a way of actually combining that promise with the dynamic import of the routes.

This for example doesn't work (or nestling each promise after another), as the callback never runs:

```
loadChildren: () => {
    return Promise.all([
      ApplicationRefPromise,
      import('./app-routes-test.routes')
    ])
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data[0]);
      console.log(data[1]);
      return data[1]._routes;
    });
}
```

This however gives me the `ApplicationRef` just fine:

```
loadChildren: () => {

    ApplicationRefPromise.then(appRef => {
      console.log(appRef);
    });

    return import('./app-routes-test.routes')
    .then(m => {
      console.log(m);
      return m._routes;
    });
```